# How do I properly return an arraylist that displays data based on userid?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, arraylist

I have been able to properly display an arraylist that displays all data in my MySQL database, however I'm having trouble how to display data based on userid.

Here is my code:

CreditsServlet.java

```
private void listTrans(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {

    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    List<Credits> creditlist = OrganizerDao.getAllCredits(id);

    for (Credits credits : creditlist) {
        if (credits.getOrganizerid() == id) {
            request.setAttribute("creditlist", creditlist);
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("credits.jsp").include(request, response);
    }
}
```

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

EDIT: CreditsDao.java

```
public static List<Credits> getAllCredits(int id) throws SQLException {

    List<Credits> creditlist=new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        Connection con= OrganizerDao.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select users.id AS organizerid, credits.invoiceid, " +
                "credits.amountin AS creditamount, attendees.name AS payee, credits.purpose, gateway.name AS gatewayname " +
                "from users, credits, attendees, gateway where credits.userid=users.id and credits.attendeeid=attendees.id " +
                "and credits.gateway=gateway.id");

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){

            Credits credits = new Credits();

            credits.setOrganizerid(rs.getInt("organizerid"));
            credits.setInvoiceid(rs.getInt("invoiceid"));
            credits.setCreditamount(rs.getDouble("creditamount"));
            credits.setPayee(rs.getString("payee"));
            credits.setPurpose(rs.getString("purpose"));
            credits.setGatewayname(rs.getString("gatewayname"));

            creditlist.add(credits);

        }
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return creditlist;

}
```

Comment: Does the method `OrganizerDao.getAllCredits(id)` returns the credits for the specific user with that id, or all the credits in the system?

Comment: The code i posted returns the credits for the specific user but only when there is one entry in the database. The moment you add more entries the code doesnt work anymore. Am not sure why that is

Comment: Then the method `OrganizerDao.getAllCredits(id)` is defective. You need to fix that method first, and fix the servlet later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way simpler than you think:

First, fix the DAO and use the parameter. Changes below:

```
public static List<Credits> getAllCredits(int id) throws SQLException {

  ...

  PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select users.id AS organizerid, credits.invoiceid, " +
    "credits.amountin AS creditamount, attendees.name AS payee, credits.purpose, gateway.name AS gatewayname " +
    "from users, credits, attendees, gateway where credits.userid=users.id and credits.attendeeid=attendees.id " +
    "and credits.gateway=gateway.id" +
    " and users.id = ?"); // Added this extra SQL code
  ps.setInt(1, id); // Added this code to use the id parameter

  ...

}
```

Then you can simply use the resulting list in the servlet:

```
private void listTrans(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
  int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
  List<Credits> creditlist = OrganizerDao.getAllCredits(id);
  request.setAttribute("creditlist", creditlist);
  response.sendRedirect("resultpage.jsp");  
}
```

This code:

- Retrieves the parameter `id` (filtering condition).
- Retrieves the credits for the specific user.
- It then places them in the attribute `creditlist` of the request scope.
- It finally redirects to the new resulting page, that will show the credits.

Comment: This solved my issue but the response.sendRedirect didnt work. i used dispatcher and include to get the code working. Thanks alot.